# Is there any way to grab all the html codes from databricks cells without selecting export cell option?

Tags: azure, export, cell, databricks, azure-databricks

To print a databricks cell along with it's output, we use Export cell option and then copy the html code. What I'm looking for here is that I want to grab all the codes of all the cells in databricks notebook without selecting export everytime.
Even if not for all the cells, I want to select the html code without using the export option.

Comment: any update? did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Unfortunately, you cannot select the cells specific to "html" codes from databricks cells.

To export all the cells to html, you can use the following method:

Click on **File** => **Export** => **HTML**

[image]

Exported HTML file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: No this does not help at all. At present I'm using the same way to take entire db script as html file.

Comment: What I need is to print specific cells only so that I could include that method into automation. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot select the cells specific to "html" codes from databricks cells.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.